# What is happening to my chocolate mint plant?

Tags: repotting, mint, blight

⁷I just got this chocolate mint plant. I repotted it since it was way too big for it's original container. It's been 4 four days and I am noticing black dots on some, not all, leaves.

Is it fungal blight? Did I just get a bad plant? Can it be saved?

[image: Mint leaves with black spots]

[image: Mint rootball][2]]